# Consequences of Using 'Public' as Database Principle Argument for sp_getapplock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server sp_getapplock takes the last parameter of [database_principal] and the default is public. Due to permissions in our development server, only 'Public' works for us.

The vast majority of examples and documentation use 'dbo' for this parameter, and don't really explain why you would want to use 'dbo' over 'Public' or the consequences of using Public over DBO.

Can anyone explain if there are any concerns for using public instead of dbo? Things to be aware of?

Comment: Why do you want to use that stored procecedure at all? There's seldom any good reason to use such locks on the server. On the other hand, it's *quite* easy to cause application deadlocks, as different clients, sessions or threads block on the same lock. This is *not* a good way to implement business transactions, or synchronize business processes

Comment: The documentation of `sp_getapplock` explains what `database_principal` is in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section. A lock is identified by the principal too, which means you can have locks for the same resource for different principals. `public` is a lock visible/accessible to al. If you use a specific account name, you create a lock specific to that account

Comment: We need a unique record created, which can be created by potentially any of a number of users, and is then shared by those users, but only one of those users should be able to create it however any of them are able to create it. So this lets us return to the user a signal to enter a wait hold while the other user creates the record and does additional setup./

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I read that multiple times, it does not explicitly state, in plain language, what you said. I suppose you could interpret that based on what's there, but it's not clearly stated. But that's par for the course with Microsoft documentation as a rule.

Comment: There's no problem with Microsoft's documentation. You're trying to interpret the docs to say something they don't. The examples *clearly* show attempts to lock client-side resource names, like form names. That was used around 2000, when people tried to use server-side locks to synchronize *client* side processes. That was abandoned *very* quickly because it doesn't scale beyond a very few concurrent users

Comment: What you describe is trying to solve a long-running *business process* issue using short-term server-side locks. You don't need locks to create unique records, a simple INSERT on a table with a generated key would work. The real problem is in `and does additional setup.`. That's shouldn't be an issue either as you could do all that inside a single transaction *unless* you intend a single *human* to manually make modifications. Which frankly, doesn't scale at all. Businesses don't work that way.

Comment: In fact, supermarkets or banks don't freeze when a single teller updates a transaction but they *used to* in the early 00s. Guess why. What everyone does since is use queues for processes that *really* need to be done sequentially, or implement checkout/checking/versioning to control how individual records are modified

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain if there are any concerns for using public instead of dbo?

With public, any other database user can acquire the lock.  When you set an alternate principal the lock is partitioned, and only the specified principal can acquire the lock.

```
exec sp_getapplock 'foo','exclusive','Transaction',null,'dbo'
```

will no block or be blocked by

```
exec sp_getapplock 'foo','exclusive','Transaction',null,'Public'
```

So if you want to guarantee that an untrusted database user can't acquire the lock, then speicfy 'dbo' and run it as dbo or in an `execute as owner` stored procedure.  This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: But `public` would block `dbo`? Our desire is completely lock down this table for inserts for this operation (we're aware of the consequences and other queries are set to not wait for a lock, and we actually prefer errors in this rare case). SQL server is actually not the best engine for this, and we understand that, but we have to use the tools we have. I appreciate this additional information as it is helpful.

Comment: If you want to lock a table, just run `select * from t with (tablockx) where 1=2`  in a transaction.  Or any DDL, like ALTER TABLE  or CREATE TRIGGER in a transaction will also block all reads and writes in every isolation level.

Comment: The problem with that is there could end up being two records for the same resource in the DB as the record needs to be created, but can  only be created by one user, but any one of a subset of users can create it, and it's indirectly tied. So we need a way to tell the calling code to enter a wait hold and the best way to do that is to attempt to get a lock without waiting and if it fails we can handle it and know someone is already creating the recod.

Comment: It's possible we're over-engineering this and we will likely look for ways to simplify it, but it's still worth understanding this procedure better.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  sp_getapplock is like a Mutex or Critical Section.  And it's used where the normal row and table locking is insufficient.

Comment: @DavidScherer you're overengineering this - whatever you want to do, you're overengineering this. You don't need such explicit locks, nor do you need to lock an entire table. The examples show this stored procedure is used like a distributed mutex, and you *don't* need that either. Such techniques were used in the (very early) 2000s but became *completely* impractical once more than a few (not even 10) concurrent users tried to use an application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean, if you have any suggestions beyond what we're doing already that can give us the behaviour we need, I'm all ears. But considering we spend 0s waiting for a lock, I'm not certain where this becomes impractical. We have a very distinct use case. A record must be created, it can be created by N distinct users, but only 1 of N distinct users should be able to create the record and any other user attempting to should fail immediately. I cannot think of another implementation that would prevent the accidental creation of a second record.